# Generating a summary table in R

Tags: r, plot, viewport

Let's consider the following character vectors:

```
M1 = c("Variable_1", "Variable_2", "Variable_3")
M2 = c("Variable_2", "Variable_4", "Variable_5")
M3 = "Variable_3"
M4 = c("Variable_1", "Variable_2", "Variable_3", "Variable_4", "Variable_5")
```

I was wondering if there is any tool/function in R that allows me to **generate** the following table based on the values of *M1*, *M2*, *M3*, and *M4*, and then **plot** the table :

[image]

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command creates a table with zeroes and ones.

```
table(do.call(rbind, lapply(c("M1", "M2", "M3", "M4"), function(x)
  data.frame(ind = x, var = get(x)))))

    var
ind  Variable_1 Variable_2 Variable_3 Variable_4 Variable_5
  M1          1          1          1          0          0
  M2          0          1          0          1          1
  M3          0          0          1          0          0
  M4          1          1          1          1          1
```

---

If you really want to have `x`s you can use:

```
tab <- table(do.call(rbind, lapply(c("M1", "M2", "M3", "M4"), function(x)
  data.frame(ind = x, var = get(x)))))

replace(replace(tab, as.logical(tab), "x"), !tab, "")

    var
ind  Variable_1 Variable_2 Variable_3 Variable_4 Variable_5
  M1 x          x          x                               
  M2            x                     x          x         
  M3                       x                               
  M4 x          x          x          x          x
```

---

Based on your comment. How to get rid of `var` and `ind` and how to use a list:

```
LL <- list(M1, M2, M3, M4)

tab <- table(do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(LL), function(x)
  data.frame(ind = x, var = LL[[x]]))))

dimnames(tab) <- unname(dimnames(tab))

replace(replace(tab, as.logical(tab), "x"), !tab, "")

    Variable_1 Variable_2 Variable_3 Variable_4 Variable_5
1 x          x          x                               
2            x                     x          x         
3                       x                               
4 x          x          x          x          x
```

Comment: Thanks Sven. Unfortunately, I was looking more for an "x" or a check mark rather..

Comment: Thanks Sven, that's perfect! Small follow-up question: what if my vectors M1 to M4 were actually elements of a list (i.e. list[[1]] is M1, list[[2]] is M2, ...). How can I use your `table()` method?

Comment: @Mariam Do the list elements have names?

Comment: No they do not.. Also, is there any way to get rid of the "ind" and "var" labels in the final table? I am going to print this table in pdf, and would rather not have those labels there...